# Theorem needed to prove a summation

Tags: summation, proof-writing, riemann-sum, summation-method

I know that the following relation holds:

$$\sum_{x=1}^y\frac{x(5x+6)}{45}=\frac{y(y+1)(10y+23)}{270}$$

But what theorem should I use to prove that relation?

Comment: $\sum_{x=1}^y x$ and $\sum_{x=1}^y x^2$

Answer (score 0):

It is known that $\sum_{x=1}^y x=\frac{y(y+1)}{2}$ and $\sum_{x=1}^y x^2=\frac{y(y+1)(2y+1)}{6}$. Refer to [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/) for example.

Your required sum will become:

$$\sum_{x=1}^y \frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{2}{15}x$$

$$=\frac{1}{9}\cdot\frac{y(y+1)(2y+1)}{6}+\frac{2}{15}\cdot\frac{y(y+1)}{2}$$

$$=y(y+1)\left[\frac{2y+1}{54}+\frac{1}{15}\right]$$

$$=y(y+1)\left[\frac{10y+5}{270}+\frac{18}{270}\right]$$

$$=y(y+1)\left[\frac{10y+23}{270}\right]$$

$$=\frac{y(y+1)(10y+23)}{270}$$

Comment: Thanks, so is there a theorem used in splitting and computing this sum?

Comment: Well, $\sum_{x=1}^y a(x)+b(x)=(a(1)+b(1))+(a(2)+b(2))+\cdots + (a(y)+b(y))=(a(1)+a(2)+\cdots+a(y))+(b(1)+b(2)+\cdots+b(y))=\sum_{x=1}^y a(x) + \sum_{x=1}^y b(y)$

Comment: You can prove the same for $\sum_{x=1}^y c\cdot f(x)=c\cdot \sum_{x=1}^y f(x)$. In particular, $\sum_{x=1}^y \sum_{i=1}^N c_i f_i(x)=\sum_{i=1}^N c_i\sum_{x=1}^y f_i(x)$ (Not really particular but)